# How to write file on ntfs properly in order to survive power outage?

Tags: windows, ntfs, corruption, recovery

My question concerns writing results of electrochemical measurements for battery testing. I have ancient PC in my lab running Win2k on NTFS.

Short time power outage is quite common issue in my case. Buying UPS is probably the best, I am still working on this.

Program, written on VB, reads data from ADC each 0.5sec and writes it to text file.

The fundamental aim is to save almost all measured data. Losing data for last several minutes is not a problem.

What can you advice me to do for data safety and easy recovery after power outages?

Which of my ideas for improving the situation can be beneficial?

1)Allocating place for file, filling it by zeros at startup and truncating at the end of measurements

2)Disable buffering at all

3)Writing data in chunks with possible checksumming in separate log-file(complicated)

Any links to successfull solution of similar problem are welcome.

Thanks for all in advance.

Comment: Start a new file every 5 minutes maybe? Add a USB memory stick and write your files to there and your main disk.

Comment: If you're simply appending a string every half second, you should be able to open the file, write the value, and close the file for every write operation. Closing the file after each operation will write it to the disk, so you wouldn't lose anything. Even a Pentium 4 should handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I could not post a comment, thus I write in an answer

@Mark Setchell Starting new file for short period of time could be good. @reasra also proposed quite similar and elegant method derived from above. Writing portion of data to file and then closing it each several seconds/minutes could be good tradeoff between computer load  and data reliability. The computer has first generation of Celeron CPU, so it`s quite slow.

@Mark Setchell writing data on another partition/media is also very beneficial.
However using flashdrives has restrictions-mostly because of low number of write cycles and avoiding write amplification.

@Mark Setchell, @reasra - thanks a lot for your aid.